# mongoose creating wrong schema

Tags: angularjs, mongoose

I am using Angular.js with Mongoose.

I have created a schema from Angular.js, and I am inserting data in the same schema.
But when I run `show collections` on MongoDB, it shows the collection name suffixed with an 's'.

For instance, I'm using the schema name `test`, and running the query shows the collection as `tests`.

Below is the code which I'm using:

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('static-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var routes = require('./routes/index');
var users = require('./routes/users');

var methodOverride=require('method-override');

var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');

app.use(favicon());
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded());
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(methodOverride(function(req, res){
    if (req.body && typeof req.body === 'object' && '_method' in req.body) {
        // look in urlencoded POST bodies and delete it
        var method = req.body._method
        delete req.body._method
        return method
    }
}));

/* app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public'))); */

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/Project');

var custSchema=new mongoose.Schema({
    custid  : String,
    name    : String,
    password: String
});

var customer= mongoose.model('test',custSchema);
console.dir(customer);

app.use(function(req,res,next){
    req.user = customer;
    next();
});


//app.use('/', routes.index);
app.get('/', routes.index);
app.get('/show',routes.list);
app.get('/new',routes.list);    
//app.post('/show',routes.create);
//app.use('/users', users);

/// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    var err = new Error('Not Found');
    err.status = 404;
    next(err);
});

/// error handlers

// development error handler
// will print stacktrace
if (app.get('env') === 'development') {
    app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
        res.status(err.status || 500);
        res.render('error', {
            message: err.message,
            error: err
        });
    });
}

// production error handler
// no stacktraces leaked to user
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
    res.status(err.status || 500);
    res.render('error', {
        message: err.message,
        error: {}
    });
});


module.exports = app;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how Mongoose operates by default.

[The documentation states](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#collection):

> Mongoose by default produces a collection name by passing the model
>   name to the `utils.toCollectionName` method. **This method pluralizes
>   the name**.

It also shows how to override this behaviour.

Comment: Thanks for that.. but it shows how to remove the '_id' from collection, but i am having issues in collection name.